# Ansible shows error: "One or more undefined variables: 'item' is undefined" when using 'with_items'

Tags: ansible

I am trying to count the instances inside an elb. This is my Ansible playbook:

```
- name: Get elb facts
  local_action:
    module: ec2_elb_facts
    name: "{{elb}}"
    region: "{{ansible_ec2_placement_region}}"
  environment: creds
  register: elb_facts

- debug:
    var: elb_facts
    verbosity: 2

- debug:
    msg: "Instance: {{ item.instances }}"
    with_items: "{{ elb_facts.elbs }}"
```

and my output (sensitive data removed):

```
TASK: [debug ] ****************************************************************
ok: [10.0.0.0] => {
    "elb_facts": {
        "changed": false,
        "elbs": [
            {
                "availability_zones": [
                    "ap-southeast-2b",
                    "ap-southeast-2a"
                ],
                "dns_name": "elbname123.ap-southeast-2.elb.amazonaws.com",
                "health_check": {
                    "healthy_threshold": 2,
                    "interval": 10,
                    "target": "TCP:0000",
                    "timeout": 5,
                    "unhealthy_threshold": 2
                },
                "instances": [
                    {
                        "id": "i-000000000000000",
                        "state": null
                    }
                ],
                "name": "accessgateway",
                "scheme": "internal",
                "security_groups": [
                    "sg-00000000"
                ],
                "subnet": [
                    "subnet-0000000",
                    "subnet-1111111"
                ],
                "vpc_id": "vpc-000000"
            }
        ],
        "invocation": {
            "module_args": "",
            "module_name": "ec2_elb_facts"
        }
    }
}

TASK: [debug ] ****************************************************************
fatal: [10.0.0.0] => One or more undefined variables: 'item' is undefined

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

So what im trying to do is just loop through and print everything inside the elb_facts, instances variable. From what I can tell it's a hash, containing a list of hashes.

I am using http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#looping-over-subelements as a reference. I cannot for the life of mine figure out why this is not working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`with_items` (and the whole family of `with_` loops) is a dictionary key defined in a task, not as a parameter to the action.

Fix the indentation:

```
- debug:
    msg: "Instance: {{ item.instances }}"
  with_items: "{{ elb_facts.elbs }}"
```