# How to loop over variables in an ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

I have the following playbook that prints out a list of the plugins that are installed on three jenkins servers:

```
---
- hosts: all
  remote_user: user
  tasks:
      - name: Obtaining a list of Jenkins Plugins
        jenkins_script:
          script: 'println(Jenkins.instance.pluginManager.plugins)'
          url: 'http://server1.usa.com:8080/'
          user: 'admin'
          password: 'password'

      - name: Obtaining a list of Jenkins Plugins
        jenkins_script:
          script: 'println(Jenkins.instance.pluginManager.plugins)'
          url: 'http://server2.usa.com:8080/'
          user: 'admin'
          password: 'password'

      - name: Obtaining a list of Jenkins Plugins
        jenkins_script:
          script: 'println(Jenkins.instance.pluginManager.plugins)'
          url: 'http://server3.usa.com:8080/'
          user: 'admin'
          password: 'password'
```

However, this is clearly not the most efficient way to do this. I looked into loops and variables within ansible playbooks- but I seem to be going in circles. Here is what I have so far:

```
- name: Obtaining a list of Jenkins Plugins
  jenkins_script:
    script: 'println(Jenkins.instance.pluginManager.plugins)'
    url: {{ item  }}
    with_items:
      - 'http://server1.usa.com:8080/'
      - 'http://server2.usa.com:8080/'
      - 'http://server3.usa.com:8080/'
    user: 'admin'
    password: 'password'
```

Here is the error message:

```
fatal: [server]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "the field 'args' has an invalid value, which appears to include a variable that is undefined. The error was: 'item' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/home/user/varspb.yml': line 5, column 9, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n  tasks:\n      - name: Obtaining a list of Jenkins Plugins\n        ^ here\n"}
```

I'm sure it is a simple mistake, but does anyone see where I am going wrong?

Comment: Please correct the indentation in your examples and post the error message Ansible gives you, it should be helpful.

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov made the changes

Comment: Strange, you should have `syntax error` with unquoted `{{ item }}`. But this exact message is caused by wrong `with_items:` indentation – should be on the same level as module name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ansible shows error: "One or more undefined variables: 'item' is undefined" when using 'with\_items'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42238934/ansible-shows-error-one-or-more-undefined-variables-item-is-undefined-when)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you start your value with a variable such as `{{ item }}`, then it needs to be quoted with intent to interpolate a variable `"{{ item }}"`. Also, you have various formatting issues in your yaml and task block. I managed to fix your task with this:

```
- name: Obtaining a list of Jenkins Plugins
  jenkins_script:
    script: 'println(Jenkins.instance.pluginManager.plugins)'
    url: "{{ item  }}"
    user: 'admin'
    password: 'password'
  with_items:
    - 'http://server1.usa.com:8080/'
    - 'http://server2.usa.com:8080/'
    - 'http://server3.usa.com:8080/'
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, that fixed the problem. I upvoted your solution.

Comment: My host file has 6 servers - and each align with a URL. However it looks like it is running through every URL for each server and not just the one URL that aligns with the host. Meaning that instead of printing out 6 lists of plugins, it prints out 36. Do you know what could be causing this.

Comment: @Joe.hail You cannot upvote my answer with your reputation level yet, but you can accept it with the check mark next to it. If you have another question, feel free to post it on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I posted another question - similar to this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42493579/ansible-playbook-looping-control-flow